# Difference between require() and await import()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, require

I would like to know the difference between `require(x)` and `await import(x)` in terms of code splitting and lazy loading. Are they both the same? If yes, then why does `await import(x)` exist in the first place as one can use `require()` statements anywhere he wants. Any in depth answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `require` is still used when you don't use Babel transpiller. Reason is that `import`, `export` keywords were added to JS in ES6 and `async/await` was added in ES8. This is why you see `require`d modules in Node.js but `imports` in React for ex.

Comment: `require` is CommonJS specific syntax that is supported by Node, but not by browsers. I predates ES modules. ES modules are standardized now  and supported in more and more environments.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.
I think you should read this:

https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b

import is when requiring an es module, that's the new ecma script standard, it has many benefits over require (common js modules)

Answer (score 1):

1. `import(x)` allows you to selectively load only the items you need, so it can help save memory
2. `import(x)` can be run asynchronously, so better performance